# finding column range of existing text box

Tags: vba, excel

I have just began using vba for excel and I am attempting to create a a macro of some type that shows the position of an already existing text box in terms of which column it starts and which column it ends. I have looked all over stack and other sites only to find macros which create a brand new text box and show the locations. I want to just show the start and ending positions of a text box on that text box and hopefully for it to update if you move the box itself. I'm just a little overwhelmed as I still don't understand the capabilities of vba yet. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image]

I have run into code creating a text box and returning the lower right corner in a dialog box but haven't been able to change this info into something useful anything to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code i found btw:

```
Sub CallTheFunction()
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = DrawPostIt(100, 150, 250, 150, "MyTextBox1")
MsgBox Cell.Address

End Sub

Function DrawPostIt(Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, _
    Height As Single, Text As String) As Range
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left, _
        Top, Width, Height).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' Yellow post-it
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Text
    Set DrawPostIt = Selection.BottomRightCell
End Function
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate the updating you can only use a workaround like the `SelectionChange` event, because there is no resize event for shapes.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Target.Parent

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes   'loop through all shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then 'that are text boxes
            'write the header cells into the text box
            shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = ws.Cells(1, shp.TopLeftCell.Column).text & " - " & ws.Cells(1, shp.BottomRightCell.Column).text
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Peh thank you for your reply and help.  I have tried to run your solution but when I try it, it gives me an empty macros menu and asks me to look it up but its not in the list any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: i figured it out thank you so much Peh. Your solution worked great.

Comment: @AmmarAhmad Yes, the macro is a event that runs on every change of cell selection. I made this as a workaround to "update" the boxes semi-automatically. Otherwise you would have to click a button to update the boxes each time you changed them.

Comment: Would I somehow be able to change the event to mouseUp? so as to run this update everytime the mouse is released? if so how can i do that? i tried doinf Worksheet_MoueUp in title but didnt work. Thanks again! @Peh

Comment: @AmmarAhmad There is no `Worksheet_MoueUp` event, so no you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using an ActiveX textbox you can look at the `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` properties.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    'ThisWorkbook is the spreadsheet that this code is in.
    'Setting a reference to the worksheet means we can run this code anywhere
    'and not just on the ActiveSheet.
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'This is the name of the shape as it appears in the Name box (just above cell A1).
    'Name can also be found in the Selection Pane when the box is selected (`Format` ribbon for the textbox).
    Set shp = wrkSht.Shapes("TextBox1")

    'Returns the column number and the column letter.
    '(Address returns something like $A$1 which can be split by the $).
    'Look at how to use With... End With blocks.
    With shp.TopLeftCell
        Debug.Print .Column & " - " & Split(.Address, "$")(1)
    End With

    With shp.BottomRightCell
        Debug.Print .Column & " - " & Split(.Address, "$")(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

Edit:  Make sure you have the `Immediate` window visible to see the results of `Debug.Print`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the text boxes in Excel (which are shapes) are not ActiveX.

Comment: @Peh - that's what it says on the Insert menu in the Controls section of the Develop ribbon.  Top section is `Form` controls and the textbox is greyed out so can't select it, bottom section says `ActiveX` controls and when I hover over it it says `Text Box (ActiveX Control)`

Comment: Hey Darren thanks for replying your answer is the first I have tried and Im getting the following error: runtime error '-2147024809 (80070057)': Thew item with the specified name wasnt found and it happens on this line->  Set shp = wrkSht.Shapes("TextBox1")

Comment: The textbox probably isn't called `TextBox1` in your file.  Manually select the textbox and see what name appears in the `Name` box - change the code to use the correct name.  The `Name` box is just above column A and usually shows the address of the selected cell.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Ahh, then we were talking about different text box types. I was talking about the built in Text box from the menu > insert > text > text box (which is not a ActiveX). Anyway the code should work for both types then.

Comment: @Peh.  I completely forgot that one existed.  Yes, it works on that to except the default name is `TextBox 1` rather than `TextBox1`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook probably that's the naming issue the OP has now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with a rectangle as a shape doing something like below, which will loop through the columns and check their width and then get the relevant start and end of your rectangle, then add the headers into your rectangle (in order to run the macro you will need either a separate button or assign it to the shape on click event, so you can move the shape then click on it and it should have the desired effect):

```
Sub foo()
LastCol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'check the last column on the first row
For i = 1 To LastCol ' loop and add the width of each column
    NewWidth = NewWidth + Sheet1.Cells(1, i).Width
    If NewWidth >= ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Left Then Exit For
    'make sure to have a shape already set up and change the name from Rectangle 2 to whatever your shape is called
    'if the left of the rectangle falls here, stop loop
Next i

For x = LastCol To 1 Step -1
    NewRight = NewRight + Sheet1.Cells(1, x).Width
    If NewRight >= ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Left + ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Width Then Exit For
Next x
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 2")).Select 'change the name of your shape
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Sheet1.Cells(1, i).Value & " to " & Sheet1.Cells(1, LastCol - x + 1).Value  'add the text from the first column
End Sub
```